# Parallel circuit between switches for bathroom fan outlet wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, bathroom, switch

While upgrading a fan switch to a timed switch I came across the wiring as pictured below. What purpose does the line daisy chaining these separate light and fan switches serve? Should I remove or what should I reconnect to?

Update: After [testing the lines with a multi-meter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wv0e_VEuZ8I&t=2s) (w/ multi-meter red node to test line, black nod to neutral) there is only one hot line (the u-shaped wire in the middle of the img.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Was the old fan switch a 3-way by any chance?

Comment: I'm not able to turn fan on from another outlet, nevertheless I think so... Updating post

Comment: That's not series, it's parallel. Well, honestly hard to tell from those pictures, but almost certainly parallel, with one hot feeding two switches, not one hot feeding one switch and the switched output of that switch feeding the next switch (which is what series would look like.)

Answer (score 1):

The parallel connection from the "line" terminal on the timer switch powers the light switch, otherwise there will be no power if removed or if connected to the "load" terminal the power will only be available when the fan switch is turned on. Below is the end result.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Having the power daisy chained is normal to provide power to multiple devices.

Comment: Btw, your answer as it stands doesn't stand alone very well if the video links die...

Comment: Ah, I see now -- no 3-ways are involved; the box is simply feeding power along to another box.

Comment: Is this the answer or should this be an edit to the original question?

Comment: @Machavity... see update